# Getting rid of rotation control in Fabric.js

Tags: fabricjs

[In this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pgschr/hsLwjtbx/123/) I have a Fabric.js text created with `lockRotation: true` to avoid rotation. The line disappeared, but the box control to rotate is still there, how to get rid of it?

HTML

```
<canvas id="c" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

Javascript

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

var text = new fabric.IText('This is the text',{
    left: 50,
    top: 50,
    fontFamily: 'Arial',
    fontWeight: 'normal',
    fontSize: 18,
    lockRotation: true,
    stroke: 'black',
    fill: 'black'
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [object.hasRotatingPoint](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#hasRotatingPoint) = false; to hide rotating point.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var text = new fabric.IText('This is the text',{
    left: 50,
    top: 50,
    fontFamily: 'Arial',
    fontWeight: 'normal',
    fontSize: 18,
    hasRotatingPoint: false,
    stroke: 'black',
    fill: 'black'
});

canvas.add(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 16):

The accepted answer is no longer valid with Fabricjs versions from 4.0 (see [changelog](http://fabricjs.com/v4-breaking-changes)). `hasRotatingPoint` has been removed in favor of a more comprehensive controls api, although the [documentation](http://fabricjs.com/controls-api) for it is still very slim.

To hide a certain control from a specific object, you have to redefine its `controls` property. Here is how you would hide the `mtr` control (Rotate):

```js
text.controls = {
    ...fabric.Text.prototype.controls,
    mtr: new fabric.Control({ visible: false })
}
```

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var text = new fabric.IText('This is the text',{
    left: 50,
    top: 50,
    fontFamily: 'Arial',
    fontWeight: 'normal',
    fontSize: 18,
    stroke: 'black',
    fill: 'black'
});
text.controls = {
    ...fabric.Text.prototype.controls,
    mtr: new fabric.Control({ visible: false })
}

canvas.add(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

Here we create a new controls object using the default ones for Text but redefining the `mtr` set.

Comment: Or `text.setControlsVisibility({ mtr: false })` for `fabric@4.5.0`.

Comment: comment above is the valid answer for the current Fabricjs

Answer (score 4):

Use `setControlsVisibility`, it works with all object type of fabricjs

```
fabric.Image.fromURL(src, (img) => {
      var oImg = img.set({
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
      })
      oImg.setControlsVisibility({ mtr: false })
      canvas.add(oImg)
      canvas.setActiveObject(oImg)
      canvas.renderAll()

    }



let newtext = new fabric.Textbox(text, {
      left: 0,
      top: 0,
      originX: 'center',
      originY: 'center',
      fontFamily: 'Inter',
      fill: '#fff',
      textAlign: 'center',}
      )
      newtext.setControlsVisibility({ mtr: false })
      canvas.add(newtext)
      canvas.setActiveObject(newtext)
      canvas.renderAll()
```

Answer (score 0):

Disabling rotation on objects sometimes is not enough. People can still select multiple objects and the rotation control point shows again. You may also want to disable the group rotation

```
fabric.Group.prototype._controlsVisibility = {
    tl: true,
    tr: true,
    br: true,
    bl: true,
    ml: false,
    mt: false,
    mr: false,
    mb: false,
    mtr: false
};
```